# JOIN in SQLITE on iphone

Tags: iphone, sqlite, select, join, request

I have a SQLite request to do and I don't know how to do it.

Here it is :

```
SELECT videoid,inappid FROM store,video 
WHERE store.paid='1' AND store.checked='1' 
AND video.inappid=store.inappid AND video.download =='0' 
ORDER BY video.inappid DESC,video.videoid;
```

--> SQL ERROR answer :     DB Error: 1 "ambiguous column name: inappid"

I explain : store and video are 2 tables.
in store, there is product referenced by 'inappid' (com.mysite.myapp.000). 'inappid' column name is the key in the table and is unique. paid and checked are just boolean in the store table.

in video, there is... video and each video has a unique key 'videoid'.  an 'inappid' column that refers to the inappid in the store table.

So my request was : select me all the inappid params of element in the store table where paid and checked are TRUE and SELECT me all the videoid of video with this inappid in the video table WHERE this video is not already downloaded.

I know I must use JOIN and ON element but I don't know how

please help Oo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because both tables contain a column `inappid`, it doesn't know which one you are wanting to return when you say `SELECT videoid,inappid FROM ...`.

One simple solution is to just explicitly pick one: `SELECT videoid,video.inappid FROM ...`

Another solution is to do your join using JOIN and USING, in which case it will know that the "inappid" columns in both tables are equivalent: `SELECT videoid,inappid FROM store JOIN video USING(inappid) WHERE store.paid='1' AND store.checked='1' AND video.download =='0' ORDER BY video.inappid DESC,video.videoid`

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT store.videoid, video.inappid FROM store,video 
WHERE store.paid='1' AND store.checked='1' 
AND video.inappid=store.inappid AND video.download =='0' 
ORDER BY video.inappid DESC,video.videoid;
```

Maybe?